# Seligman Baer tikkun

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, torah-reading, safrus

Does anyone know where to get a scan of R' Seligman Baer's tikkun korim, or other older Western European tikkunei-korim? A complete scan of a Western Ashkenazi sefer Torah would also work.

Edit:
I believe I once saw someone mention there being one on Otzar haChochma, but I couldn't navigate their site at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can find good scans of Baer and Delitszch's Masoretic Bible at:

http://www.archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A%22Baer%2C+S.+%28Seligmann%29%2C+1825-1897%22

Wish they'd turn Bereishis (https://archive.org/details/libergenesis00baer) the right way up!

Comment: I'm looking for something which shows the sta"m sofer of the time, so not this.